# Can I make runtime validation of method parameters based on jsr-305 annotations?

Tags: java, runtime, jsr305

Although JSR-305 is about static analysis of code. Its' run-time counterpart isn't ready yet. Following my question I want to ask if there's a suitable annotation processor which could detect that method parameters are not correct based on annotations for those parameters?

=== Edit ===

What I'm actually looking for is not a model validation (model = collection of beans) but something more like aspect weaving I could seamlessly integrate into my tests suite.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be something like the standard bean validation scheme established in [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) (implemented by, for instance, [hibernate validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html)).

Btw, looks like JSR-305 has been inactive since 2006, so I wouldn't hold my breath on that to develop further...

Comment: Following your proposal one could also look at [Spring 3 Validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).